# Java Classpath problem

Tags: java, classpath

I have a Java Program that references a Jar File.

The Jar File is present in the same directory as the .class File but when I try to run the program from console, I get NoClassDefFound error :-(

Alternatively it runs Ok from Eclipse.

Why ?

Answer (score 7):

The `java` program will not automatically include JAR files in its class path. You add a JAR file to its class path via the `-classpath` option. For example:

```
java -classpath .;yourJarFile.jar your.MainClass
```

Eclipse is automatically adding the JAR file whenever you run the program.

Note: The `-classpath` option expects a semicolon (`;`) when running on Windows and a colon (`:`) otherwise.

Comment: I guess you are right. Now if the Jar File uses any other Jar File I should add that too?

Comment: Thanks mate. 
Dude can you give me an example of two Jar Files. ? On a unix system.

Comment: You just separate all the JAR file names with a colon (`:`) on a UNIX system:

`java -classpath .:firstJarFile.jar:secondJarFile.jar your.MainClass

Answer (score 3):

JAR files are not automatically included in the classpath.  You can add a `Class-Path` entry and a `Main-Class` entry to the to JAR file containing the main method that you wish to execute. Then you can execute your code like so:

```
java -jar yourJarFile.jar
```

See the [JAR File Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) for more details.

or specify the classpath on the command line:

```
java -classpath lib1.jar:lib2.jar:yourJarFile.jar your.MainClass
```